# prevent render attempt if item not loaded from state yet

Tags: reactjs, cloudinary

I am requesting an image from cloudinary and at face value everything seems fine as I can see the image on the frontend as intended. But when looking at chrome dev tools I can see that first there was a 404 error which shows a call to the path where the image is stored but without the image name. For the second call which is successful, there is the path and the image name.

So, It appears that before the image name is not yet loaded from the state at the time the first request is made. I did try the && conditional check but that had the same result ie:

```
{this.state.bgImg && this.state.bgImg}
```

Then I tried:

```
{this.state.bgImg ? this.state.bgImg : "fakeImage.jpg"}
```

And in dev tools I see it actually tried to get that fakeImage.jpg

How can I prevent this?

```
class Home extends Component {
  state = {
    title: "",
    bgImg: "",
    categories: []
  };

  async componentDidMount() {
    const response = await getHero();
    const { data: categories } = await getCategories();
    this.setState({
      title: response.data.title,
      categories,
      bgImg: response.data.bgImg
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <NavBar />
        <Hero
          title={this.state.title}
          bgImg={this.state.bgImg && this.state.bgImg}
        />
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}
export default Home;


const imageUrl = process.env.REACT_APP_CLOUDINARY_URL;

class Hero extends Component {
  render() {
    const { title, bgImg } = this.props;
    return (
      <section
        className="section-hero d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center mb-5"
        style={{
          backgroundImage: `linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)), url(${imageUrl}/somepath/${bgImg})`

        }}
      >
        <Container className="text-center text-white">
          <h1>{title}</h1>
        </Container>
      </section>
    );
  }
}
export default Hero;
```

Comment: We need to see how you are fetching the image from cloudinary

Comment: What's the context of those snippets in your post? Are they in an img tag's src prop?  Do you have the option of simply not rendering the tag as a whole if the image is missing (i.e. `{this.state.bgImg ? <img src={this.state.bgImg} /> : null}`)?

Comment: @user8463989 try my solution below and let me know if that helps :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the initial render of your `Home` component, you pass an empty string to `Hero` for the `bgImg` prop. You will get a 404 error because no image was found in this path.

```
url(${imageUrl}/somepath/${bgImg}) <--- bgImg is an empty string on first render.
```

To workaround this, you can just do a conditional check so that your `Hero` component only renders when the `bgImg-state` in `Home` is a truthy value, which it will be after the completed fetch in `componentDidMount`.

So for the first render we will give `bgImg` a default value of `null` (that makes sense) because there is no-value. Hero component will not be used yet (so no 404 error). Then after `componentDidMount`, everything will work as expected.

```
class Home extends Component {
  state = {
    title: "",
    bgImg: null,
    categories: []
  };

  async componentDidMount() {
    const response = await getHero();
    const { data: categories } = await getCategories();
    this.setState({
      title: response.data.title,
      categories,
      bgImg: response.data.bgImg
    });
  }

  render() {
    const { bgImg } = this.state
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <NavBar />
        { bgImg && (
           <Hero
              title={this.state.title}
              bgImg={bgImg}
           />
        )}
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}
export default Home;
```